# Backing Up the save data on the PS3.

Tags: technical-issues, ps3

My hard Drive is dying and I want to back up my save data on the PS3, but I just want to back up the save data and I have soo many games and data I want to save, so, it's really boring and time consuming doing it manually and if I use the back up utility it says I need 236gb to back up, meaning, is backing up games and dlc's, right? So, is there any way to JUST back up the save data? all of it?

Comment: The guide I left on your other post had information about backing up your data. Once again, [the link is here](http://www.techradar.com/us/how-to/gaming/how-to-upgrade-your-ps3-hard-drive-1285911)

Comment: @Kaizerwolf The Guide there just say that I should use the Back up data utility, which doesn't work for me, since is not just the save data, is everything on the PS3. Also, claims that PS+ allows me to save all the data in one go, which doesn't happen also. The only way that I have found is to do it manually. That's why I was asking.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf but anyway, doesn't matter anymore. I did it manually.